# Using Axios to Send Data to Backend Flask

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

Problem:
I am having a problem sending my data to Flask Backend, with react being my front-end. I am using axios. I define an axios call within an onClick function which is triggered by the user entering information into a form and clicking submit. Looking at my server it seems the POST request is coming through, the when I click submit, the console.log I have in the .then portion after the axios call is not being displayed the the page is redirected back to my home page. I was wondering why this would be happening.

Here is the Flask Backend:

```
@app.route('/post',methods=['POST'])
def testPost():
    name = request.form.get("Variable","")
    return jsonify(name=name)
```

Here is the onClick with the Axios call:

```
const onClick = e => {
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/post').then(res => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log(res)
                }
                
            ).catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            })
          }
```

Here is the Form:

```
<div className="users-information">
                            <form className="patient-form" id="patient-form" name="patient-form" >

                                <input type="text" name="Variable" id="Variable" />
                                
                                <label>
                                    Address: 
                                    <input name="Address" id="users-address" />
                                </label>

                                <label>
                                    City: 
                                    <input name="City" id="users-city" />
                                </label>

                                <label>
                                    State: 
                                    <input name="State" id="users-state" />
                                </label>

                                <label >
                                    Zip: 
                                    <input name="Zip" id="users-zip" />
                                </label>

                                <input type='submit' value='Submit' onClick={onClick} />     
                             </form>
                        </div>
```

This is happening inside a class component, and the onClick is defined after the render().

Comment: The `e.preventDefault()` is within `then`. You should put it out side `then` right before your axios call. Not sure if that is what is causing this issue. But have you tried that ?

Comment: @EmmanuelPonnudurai It still takes me to the homepage :(